# Unwanted delay on CSS transition. Text underline changes before actual text

Tags: css, button, css-transitions

I have created a button with a css transition that changes color on :hover. I want the border and shadow of the box, and the text inside the button to transition color at the same time.

But it looks like a weird bug, since on :hover the text-underline changes at the same time as the rest of the button, but the actual text starts it transition after the others are finished transitioning.

PUG:

```
a(href="#")
  .button 
   p read more
```

SASS:

```
$darkColor: #111210
$accentColor: #DD452A

a
  color: $darkColor
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out

  &:hover
    color: $accentColor

.button
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  border: solid 1px $darkColor
  border-radius: 20px
  height: 40px
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px $darkColor
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out

  &:hover
    cursor: pointer
    border: solid 1px lighten($darkColor, 50%)
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px lighten($darkColor, 50%)
```

[See codepen of it here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdjvXV?editors=1100)

[Video demonstration.](http://d.pr/v/56lob) (Wait a bit to see a slow version)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most probably due to the fact that the text-decoration property which by default controls the underline can not be transitioned. If you need it to transition perfectly in-sync with the other elements, I'd suggest to remove the decoration:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

and simulate it either with box-shadow or border-bottom

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #000; /*or*/
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
```

Either way the property will transition as expected but I tend to use box-shadow as it doesn't affect the size of the element.

Hope that helps.

Martin

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at the video demonstration posted above, and especially last part in slow motion, you can se that the text-decoration property is transitioned. The color fades in over time. The problem is that the underline and text are triggered at different intervals somehow.

Comment: Indeed upon closer inspection the `text-decoratioin-color` property is animatable. You can add it explicitly to your `:hover` declaration and see how it goes but I'd still refrain using it at least because of the unreliable browser support. For example on my Firefox/Windows it doesn't behave at all as on the video.

Comment: `text-decoration` is being animated as it should. It's the text color which is animated incorrectly. It starts it's animation after the other transitions are done. But there is no delay specified.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to underline the text using an alternative to text-decoration: underline.

This CSS does the trick.

```
$darkColor: #111210
$accentColor: #DD452A

a
  color: $darkColor
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out
  text-decoration: none

  &:hover
    color: $accentColor

.button
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  border: solid 1px $darkColor
  border-radius: 20px
  height: 40px
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px $darkColor
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out

  &:hover
    cursor: pointer
    border: solid 1px lighten($darkColor, 50%)
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px lighten($darkColor, 50%)

.button p
  display: inline-block
  position: relative

  &:after
    content: ''
    position: absolute
    left: 0
    display: inline-block
    height: 1em
    width: 100%
    border-bottom: 1px solid
    margin-top: 0px
```

[See CodePen of it here.](https://codepen.io/glennfriesen/pen/VbBBjV)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still persists. I want the border around the button to transition at the same time as the text inside it (have to color change of both elements start and stop at the same time). No it's a delay between the two. Text color transition starts when border color transition ends.

Answer (score -1):

Use this styles its works for me

```
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FAFAFA 2%, #EFEFEF 98%);
 border-color: #C5C5C5 #C5C5C5 #BCBCBC;
 border-image: none;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset, 0 -1px 0 #E7E7E7 inset, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 color: #191919;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: 400;
     min-width: 81px;
 height: 37px;
 outline: medium none;
 padding: 0 16px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
 white-space: nowrap;
     font-size:14px;
 line-height: 36px;
```